# Unable to connect socket after disconnect in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I was trying to implement a chat app using W3Csocket in ReactJs (class component). The issue is the socket disconnects due to various reasons. I want the socket to reconnect whenever it disconnects so that the chat app works even when it is open in the browser window for a long time.

I am connecting the socket in constructor like:-

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state= {
      client: new W3CWebSocket(socket_url)
   }
}
```

here is the code used to listen to messages.

```
this.state.client.onmessage = (message) => {
   console.log("Socket recieved message...");
};
```

here is the code I had implemented to reconnect the socket.

```
this.state.client.onclose = (e) => {
   console.log("Socket closed...");
   this.setState({client: new W3CWebSocket(socket_url)});
};
```